# Reacjs getting the generic "unexpected token" error message

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, jsx

I'm new to Reactjs and I am getting the "unexpected token error" in my first attempt to build a series of components.

My console reports this:

```
SyntaxError: http://localhost:3004/app.js: Unexpected token (14:11)

 class AnnouncementList extends React.Component
 {
    render() {
             ^
          return (
```

I got really frustrated when searching the console output on Google it really messes up when we insert code in the search keywords. I have the babel plugin set up.

```
   class AnnouncementsDashboard extends React.Component 
    {
   render() {
       return (
      <div>
       <AnnouncementList/>
      <div>
      );
   }
 }

  class AnnouncementList extends React.Component
 {
    render() {
        return (
          <div>
          <Announcement />
          </div>
          );
   }
 }


  class Announcement extends React.Component
  {
      render(){
          return (

         <div></div>
       );
  }
 }


      /**
     * @jsx React.DOM
     */


   ReactDOM.render(<AnnouncementDashboard />,     document.getElementById('container'));
```

updated, html included.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

 <html>

  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <!-- Disable browser cache -->
   <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
   <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
   <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
   <title>Project Two: Timers</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/semantic-ui/semantic.min.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
   <script src="vendor/babel-core-5.8.25.js"></script>
   <script src="vendor/react.js"></script>
   <script src="vendor/react-dom.js"></script>
   <script src="vendor/uuid.js"></script>
   <script src="vendor/fetch.js"></script>
   </head>

  <body>
     <div id="main" class="main ui">
     <h1 class="ui dividing centered header">Timers</h1>
     <div id="container"></div>
  </div>
    <script type="text/babel" src="./client.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="./helpers.js"></script>

   <script type="text/babel" data-plugins="transform-class-properties" src="./app.js"></script>


  </body>

</html>
```

Adding a scenario that works:

```
  /* eslint-disable react/prefer-stateless-function */
 /* eslint-disable react/jsx-boolean-value */

 class AnnouncementDashboard extends React.Component 
  {
     render() {
     return (<div>"I'm am React, when something goes wrong I always say  - unexpected token" </div>);
   }
  }






 ReactDOM.render(<AnnouncementDashboard/>, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: get rid of your ; at the end of the render function

Comment: The reason for this error is because the syntax is invalid. So I don't think your Babel setup works, can you provide more info about that?

Comment: Babel is set up, I've tested the application with other components from another file.

Comment: I took away the ; at the end of file and the error persisted.

Comment: Do you use webpack with your babel ?

Comment: I don't use webpack.

Comment: do you have `.babelrc` ?

Comment: have you tried putting `AnnouncementList` in a seprate file and then `export default AnnouncementList` and then import it inisde main component `AnnouncementDashboard`

Comment: I will include my html file.

Comment: The id of my element is "container" I pasted old version of my code. I have corrected that now.

Comment: I updated my question if I changed the file to the code at the bottom of post it works.

Comment: @DiegoAlves have you tried create-react-app ? That seems like it would be much easier then loading files in script tags like you have it now

Comment: With ten years of programming I can say to you that this is one the weirdest errors I have seen. I pasted some components from another file and pasted them in the app.js file and it worked I then removed all the code inside the render function of the components and it worked as well, I then included the contents that I wanted and it worked. I thought with myself "it began to transpile now" I, then, pasted the code in this post and it gives me error. I checked and rechecked several times the code and I just can't spot the error.

Comment: AnnouncementsDashboard component is missing a closing slash on the container div

Answer (score 0):

the only issue I see is the AnnouncementsDashboard component is missing a closing slash on the container div. Also I would restructure the code to use stateless functions. Unless you plan on adding state to them later on.

```
const Announcement = () => {
  return (
    <div></div>
  );
}

const AnnouncementList = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Announcement />
    </div>
  );
}

const AnnouncementsDashboard = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <AnnouncementList/>
    </div>
  );
}
```